# error when looping through xml files in directory with XmlTextReader

Tags: c#, loops, xmlreader

I am using the following code to loop through a directory, looking for xml files and readind them in:

```
XmlReader reader = null;

foreach (string file in files)
{
   try
   {
     System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(file);

     string fext = fi.Extension;
     if (fext == ".xml")
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Processing file:" + fi.Name);
         reader = XmlReader.Create(fi.Name);
       **//BUT THIS WORKS---> reader = new XmlReader(@"\\10.00.100.11   \Data\Cognos\ReportOutput\Test\Risk Rating Exception Detail (LN-133-D)-en-us_2012-04-14T031017814Z-pdf_desc.xml");**

          while (reader.Read())
          {
              switch (reader.NodeType)
              {
                 case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                      Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);
                      Console.WriteLine(">");
                      break;
                 case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                      Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
                      break;
                 case XmlNodeType.EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                      Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                      Console.WriteLine(">");
                      break;
              }

           }

           reader.Close();

       }

    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
    {
     // If file was deleted by a separate application or thread since the call to TraverseTree() then just continue.
         Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
         continue;
    }

}
```

When I use XML.Create on the single file (see BUT THIS WORKS), I can read everything in that document. When I use it with fi.Name, I get to see the message "Processing file: ", then, for every single xml file in the directory, I see "Could not find file 'C:\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MoveReportsTest\MoveReportsTest\bin\Debug\.

I tried moving the reader instantiation around, at first, it was instantiated for every file, I tried moving the reader.Close() around, thinking I can't instantiate the same reader for every file, but it didn't change anything (same error). The 'could not find file message is not coming from any catch phrase... I am clueless... please help! Thanks!

Comment: fi.Name seems suspicious.  You may want fi.FullName instead.  You can also try adding "catch(Exception exception)" to catch more than just FileNotFound.  That could help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you refer to  `fi.Name` it picks just the *name* of the file. If you in the path you provide only the name of the file, the *default* path will be the folder where you binaries are, so that one you see in exception : `C:\Documents and Settings\\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MoveReportsTest\MoveReportsTest\bin\Debug\`.

Pass *complete* path to the `XML` file you gonna read => `fi.FullName`.

Comment: That was the problem, thank you, however, now it's behaving erratically, I get to see a bunch of tags before I even get to see the "Processing file:.." display, which makes no sense. Am I using the reader.Close() correctly? (just ouside the loop through the xml file)? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: thanks again, it looks like is stops processing after reading in 2 files, I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

By the error, it sounds like you are searching for a file in a relative location, however keep in mind that it will look for a relative location if you use [`fi.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.name.aspx) only, I would suggest using [`fi.FullName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname.aspx) if you are not using a relative location.

```
FileInfo -> C:/Location/File.Ext
FileInfo.Name -> File.Ext
FileInfo.FullName -> C:/Location/File.Ext

reader = XmlReader.Create(fi.FullName);
```